# Logical Grouping of Radiobuttons in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

[image]

I have two **vbox** panels. In each of these is a radio button.

I want these two radio buttons to belong to the same **radio group**. However when I look at **RadioGroup** in extjs it seems to indicate that it is an xtype (ie. like a component, it can't be spread out across other panels). I am not looking for a *visual* grouping of the radio buttons, but rather a *logical* grouping.

Comment: Have you tried it "the HTML way"? Just give them the same `name`...

Comment: ahhh, thanks :) add as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You could try something like that :

```
        ...
        xtype : "form",
        layout : "anchor", 
        items : [ 
            {
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                columns: 2,
                vertical: true,
                items: [
                    { boxLabel: 'Client [Pfad/Dateiname]', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1', checked: true },
                    { boxLabel: 'Server [file name]', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2'}
                ]
            },{
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                fieldLabel: '',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            },{
                xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                fieldLabel: '',
                // The body area will contain three text fields, arranged
                // horizontally, separated by draggable splitters.
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype : 'button',
                    text  : 'Durchsuchen',
                    flex  : 2
                }, {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text  : 'Dateiauswahl',
                    flex  : 2
                }]
            }
         ]
         ....
```

Comment: thanks, yes that works, but the layout is different. The radio buttons have to line up exactly above the text fields. I think the answer from @Alexander is what I am going with.

Comment: if you use a form with a anchor layout, the radiobuttons should be align with the textfields.